# onbaording of a project into team city 7.0 whrere the project is running in jdk 1.5 and ant 1.;5

Tags: java, continuous-integration, teamcity, build-process, teamcity-7.0

I am new to the team city as it is being used in our development environment and I have gone through its official website and to know more about it , but now my query is that I am stuck up in an very odd situation that is my project  is in java and it uses jdk 1.5 and ant 1.5 now due to certain restrictions i can not upgrade my project to jdk 1.5 and 1.5 so i have to use jdk 1.5 only and similar case with ant also , now I have to onboard my project onto teamcity version 7 , but I have found that team city 7 minimum requirement is that you should have jdk 1.6 at least and ant version 1.8 at least which i do not have now please advise in such situation how can i set up or on board my project in teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity is itself written in Java, and so it requires JDK 1.6.  However, that doesn't stop you also installing JDK1.5 as well as JDK1.6 on your TeamCity server and using Java 1.5 to build your project.  (Our TeamCity server has JDK 1.6 and 1.7 installed on it and doesn't have a problem with that.)

I also can't see a problem with the Ant versions.  TeamCity 7 ships with Ant 1.8.2, but that doesn't stop you using Ant 1.5.  I haven't found a way to tell TeamCity to use an alternative version of Ant, but you can always use the [command-line runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Command+Line) to run the correct version of Ant if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so what i grasp from your reply is that i can use jdk 1.5 in building my project and team city server will not have any problem with that. more over could you please share any url on which it is showing that jdk 1.5 , that will be a great help.Thanks in advance

Comment: "please share any url on which it is showing that jdk 1.5" ?  I don't understand your comment.  Ant is normally used for running Java builds, but as I have already explained, you can use the command-line runner to run almost anything, regardless of what JDK you use.